# Unable to hide the column header based on the boolean value in the component

Tags: angular

I am trying to show and hide a header and row based on a boolean value in component. I am able to hide the specific td but not able to hide the specific column. In the example below , I am trying to hide Last Edited row which includes th and td element. If I set the boolean variable to false, the td for that column is not shown but how do i hide the header. It doesn't seem to work if I put the following condition

```
  <th *ngIf="c == ColumnNames[1] && showCol""
```

Html

```
 <div *ngIf="LegalFundClasses && LegalFundClasses.LegalFundClassDetailsViewModel && ColumnNames">
     <table class="fundClassesTable table-striped">
      <tr *ngFor="let c of ColumnNames">
        <th [ngClass]="c != ColumnNames[2] ? 'tableItem bold' : 'cellbgcolor'" >{{ c }}</th>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let f of LegalFundClasses.LegalFundClassDetailsViewModel; let i=index">
          <td class="tableItem" *ngIf="c == ColumnNames[0]">{{f.Description}}</td>
          <td class="tableItem" *ngIf="c == ColumnNames[1] && showCol">{{f.AuditSummary}}</td>
          <td class="tableItem" *ngIf="c == ColumnNames[2]">{{f.Id}}</td
        </ng-container>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Component

```
 public showCol: boolean = false;
 public ColumnNames: string[] = ['Legal Class Name',
                                    'Last Edited',
                                    'Legal Class ID'
                                  ];
```

Here is the fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/zyk9xhd1/9/

Answer (score 0):

You can put condition in both th and td tag

```
<table class="fundClassesTable table-striped" border="1">
      <tr *ngFor="let c of ColumnNames" >
        <th *ngIf="c == ColumnNames[1] && showCol" [ngClass]="c != ColumnNames[2] ? 'tableItem bold' : 'cellbgcolor'" >{{ c }}</th>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let f of data">
          <td class="tableItem" *ngIf="c == ColumnNames[0]">{{f.Description}}</td>
          <td class="tableItem" *ngIf="c == ColumnNames[1] && showCol">{{f.AuditSummary}}</td>
          <td class="tableItem" *ngIf="c == ColumnNames[2]">{{f.Id}}</td>
        </ng-container>
      </tr>
      </table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/viethien/w5rq3ghv/16/

Comment: Isnt that wrong ? If you notice the other two rows arent showing and the column headers are too not showing

Answer (score 0):

You are better off putting the condition on the whole `tr`

With the code below, it'll only display the rows based on a boolean array declared in the component

```
  <tr *ngFor="let c of ColumnNames; let rowIndex = index">
  <ng-container *ngIf="rowVisibility[rowIndex]">
    <th [ngClass]="c != ColumnNames[2] ? 'tableItem bold' : 'cellbgcolor'" >{{ c }}</th>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let f of data">
      <td class="tableItem" *ngIf="c == ColumnNames[0]">{{f.Description}}</td>
      <td class="tableItem" *ngIf="c == ColumnNames[1]">{{f.AuditSummary}}</td>
      <td class="tableItem" *ngIf="c == ColumnNames[2]">{{f.Id}}</td>
    </ng-container>
 </ng-container>
</tr>
```

**component.ts**

```
constructor(){

    //decide which row ro show
    public rowVisibility = [true, //1strow
     false, //2nd row
     true//3rd row
];
```

[Example on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7s918zbm/)

Comment: I think you have misunderstood my question. As per the example that I have shared there are three rows. I need to hide and display the middle row that is Last Edited based on a boolean value. I have checkbox with which I am toggling and setting the boolean value. For sake of simplicity, I have just declared a boolean value in the component.If the value of the variable is false then I need hide the entire row otherwise set it to true.

Comment: @Tom That's why  I said you have to add the condition that you want. Check this updated example: https://jsfiddle.net/nm10Lr83/4/

Comment: It works but say what If the third row is based on another boolean value say how will that fit into the condition. Say the other variable is showLastRow  and that coumn is columnName[2]. I need to also display this row based on the true or false value of showLastRow  and not showMiddleRow

Comment: @Tom I modified my answer

Comment: I am not sure how this will work in my scenrio as not all the rows have true or falso value. Currently I am having around 57 columnNames and values. There is checkbox on ColumnName[44] which sets the value to true or false. Based on that ,I am hiding three rows Namely 45,46,47 based on the boolean value hence my condition is  <ng-container *ngIf="c != ColumnNames[45] && c != ColumnNames[46] && c != ColumnNames[47] || isHurdle;" >

Comment: Similary I have checbox in ColumnNames[51], which on selection shows  ColumnNames[52]

Comment: Like I said, just assign the correct boolean value to the `rowVisibility` array